# Adding a array list to arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;
class test2{
    
    static void fun(int i,int arr[],List<Integer> l,int n,List<List<Integer>> res){
        if(i==n){
            if(l.size()!=0){
                //System.out.println(l.size());
                res.add((l));
                //System.out.println(res);
            }
            //System.out.println(l);
            return;
        }
        l.add(arr[i]);
        fun(i+1,arr,l,n,res);
        //System.out.println(l);
        l.remove(l.size()-1);
        //System.out.println(l);
        fun(i+1,arr,l,n,res);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<>();
        fun(0,arr,l,n,res);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

[image]

in fun function while i am adding a List to other List it is adding empty list i could find the reason can somebody help me this program is about finding the different combinations of given array

Comment: `res` does not contain multiple Lists;  it contains multiple references to one List.  Your program is adding to, and removing from, that one List.  `res.add(l)` does not create copies of a List, it just adds a reference that points to the List.  You probably want to add `l = new ArrayList<>(l);` right after your `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `res.add((new ArrayList<>(l))` instead of  `res.add((l))`.

### Why should use (new ArrayList<>(existing_list))?

When you update any primitive value then put in a list you can update again that primivite value. That does not change the value in list. But an object does not work like that. Well we can say it causes kind of pointer. When you update an object then it updates the values in  its address. Let me show you a short example.

```
public class MyObject {


   private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

   public MyObject() {
      list.add("added in Constructor");
   }

   public List getList() {
    return list;
   }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    System.out.println("--> Object list (Before added anything in main) : ");
    myObject.getList().forEach(System.out::println);

    List list = myObject.getList();
    list.add("added in Main");

    System.out.println("--> local list : ");
    list.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("--> Object list (After added a value in main) : ");
    myObject.getList().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

And the ouput is :

```
--> Object list (Before added anything in main) : 
added in Constructor
--> local list :
added in Constructor
added in Main
--> Object list (After added a value in main) : 
added in Constructor
added in Main
```

I did not set up a new Arraylist or create new one but my private list in MyObject is updated even if I just do changes in main function.

But instead of `list` If I returned `new Array<>(list)` then even if I update the list in main, my list would never change. Because  I return another address with `new Array<>(list)`. So you should add your list with another addres. I mean another Arraylist. So you can use `res.add((new ArrayList<>(l))` instead of  `res.add((l))`.